# How to get callback response from browser in an activity

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-webview, auth0

I launch following URI from activity in a browser.

```
Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browser.setData(uriBuilder.build());
startActivity(browser);
```

It launches google sign in page, after sign in it closes the browser, and takes me back to the activity. I want to get the response of the URL in the activity.

I am using this method, but it always gets null.

```
private void checkForInstagramData() {
        final Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
        if(data != null && data.getScheme().equals("sociallogin") && data.getFragment() != null) {
            final String accessToken = data.getFragment().replaceFirst("access_token=", "");
            if (accessToken != null) {
                // handleSignInResult(...);
            } else {
                // handleSignInResult(...);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I want to get the response of the URL in the activity" -- that is not possible, sorry. Use `WebView` for that sort of tight integration of Web content with your app. Or, use a dedicated Google sign-in API, if there is one. "I am using this method, but it always gets null" -- that is the `Intent` that was used to create your activity in the first place. It has nothing to do with the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` that you launched.

Comment: @CommonsWare : can this be achieved by custom tabs?

Comment: Possibly -- I have never used those personally.